# Error retrieving models from backbone collections once there is idAttribute = '_id'

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have a Model user set to be like this:

```
 User = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot: '/users',

      defaults: {
        id: '',
        username: '',
        password: ''
      },

      idAttribute: '_id',

      initialize: function () {
        console.log('User initiated');
      }

    });
```

And Collection to be like this:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: "/users",

    model: User,

  });

  Users = new Users();
```

Then when I'm trying to get the models in my view using 
`Users.fetch()`, I'm only getting back one result in the "collection" array no matter how many results I have on the backend.

However, after I remove the idAttribute: '_id' from Model User, I get the exact number of results as the backend.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

p.s.
As I went into the console, it seems that Users.fetch() was fired up the same amount of times as the number of users I have (each time the callback collection has only 1 model in it). So basically the last call overrides all previous ones and shows only the last result.

But I still have no idea what really is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally happens when your id attribute is undefined for all models, or otherwise the same value. Check that the value `_id` is defined and distinct in the response.

*EDIT:*

Are you sure you aren't trying to reference `id` without the underscore? If that's the case you can leave out the `idAttribute` property as `id` is the default value.

Comment: I realized I put the "idAttribute: '_id' " in the wrong place, it should be inside the "defaults" brackets for model definition. Thanks though!